# Splinter (python library) import not being recognized

Tags: python-3.x, splinter

My code begins as follows:

```
from splinter import Browser

executable_path = {'executable_path': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'}

with Broswer('chrome', **executable_path) as browser:
```

This is how it begins on splinter's own documentation. I've also tried this without the parameters for Browser, still nothing.

When I run this file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getBookData.py", line 5, in <module>
    with Broswer() as browser:
NameError: name 'Broswer' is not defined
```

I've installed splinter, I'm importing Browser; I can't find anything on this error and I have no idea what's causing it. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: That's pretty funny. Computers cannot generally correct your spelling errors for you.

Comment: @xaav I actually didn't even realize I did that... wow. Thanks lol